# Regex to delete words with numbers

Tags: php, regex

I would like to delete words with numbers (reference) or small words (2 characters or less) into my product name but I can't find the good regex.

Some examples:

- "Chaine anti-rebond ECS-2035" should become **"Chaine anti-rebond"**
- "Guide 35 cm Oregon Intenz" should become **"Guide Oregon Intenz"**
- "Tronçonneuse sans fil AKE 30 LI - Guide 30 cm 36 V" should become **"Tronçonneuse sans fil AKE - Guide"**

I'm doing this in PHP:

```
preg_replace('#([^A-Za-z-]+)#', ' ',' '.wd_remove_accents($modele).' ');
```

Comment: "delete words with numbers (reference) or small words (lte 2 chars)" thats why

Comment: No you cannot make it like this unless you should provide the function with exact matches to find in the string with numbers. e.g. you should provide with cm, li,V,ecs etc

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to do everything in RegExp you know:

```
<?php

$str = "Chaine anti-rebond ECS-2035 cm 30 v";
$result = array();

$split = explode(" ", $str); //Split to an array

foreach ($split as $word) {
    if ((strlen($word) <= 2) || (preg_match("|\d|", $word))) {  //If word is <= 2 char long, or contains a digit
        continue;                                               //Continue to next iteration immediately 
    }
    $result[] = $word;                                          //Add word to result array (would only happen if the above condition was false)
}

$result = implode(" ", $result);                                //Implode result back to string

echo $result;
```

For word based string manipulation, parsing the string itself, conditioning exactly what you want on a word basis, is often much better than a string-level RegExp.

Comment: then what about `ECS` in this string `Chaine anti-rebond ECS-2035` should become `Chaine anti-rebond`????????

Answer (score 2):

To deal with unicode characters like in `tronçonneuse` you could use:

```
/\b(?:[\pL-]+\pN+|\pN+[\pL-]+|\pN+|\pL{1,2})\b/
```

where `\pL` stands for any letter and `\pN` stands for any digit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for the combinations in your example the following regex would do:

```
/\b(?:[-A-Za-z]+[0-9]+|[0-9]+[-A-Za-z]+|\d{1,2}|[A-Za-z]{1,2})\b/
```

Then just replace the match with an empty string.

However, it doesn't allow for strings like `aaa897bbb` - just `aaa786` or `876aaa` (and an optional dash).
I don't know what it is that you require - you would have to specify the rules in more detail before the regex can be refined.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements aren't specific enough for a final answer, but this would do it for your example:

```
$subject = 'Tronçonneuse sans fil AKE 30 LI - Guide 30 cm 36 V';
$regex = '/(\\s+\\w{1,2}(?=\\W+))|(\\s+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\\d+)/';
$result = preg_replace($regex, '', $subject);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use preg_replace_callback and filter in the callback function http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

This will work for all 3 test strings:

```
<?php

$str = "Tronçonneuse sans fil AKE 30 LI - Guide 30 cm 36 V";

function filter_cb($matches)
{
    $word = trim($matches[0]);

    if ($word !== '-' && (strlen($word) <= 2 || (preg_match("/\d/", $word)))) {
        return '';
    }

    return $matches[0];
}

$result = preg_replace_callback('/([\p{L}\p{N}-]+\s*)/u', "filter_cb", $str);

echo trim($result);
```