# How to remove special/accented characters and words with digits?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to create slugs. My string is like this: `$string='möbel#*-jérôme-mp3-how?';`

**Step: 1**

First, I want to remove special characters, non-alphanumeric and non-latin characters from this string.

Like this: `$string='möbel-jérôme-mp3-how';`

Previously, I used to have only english characters in the string.

So, I used to do like this: `$string = preg_replace("([^a-z0-9])", "-", $string);`

However, since I also want to retain foreign characters, this is not working.

**Step: 2**

Then, I want to remove the all the words that have one or more numbers in them.

In this example string, I want to remove the word mp3 as it contains one or more numbers.

So, the final string looks like this: `$string='möbel-jérôme-how';`

I used to do like this:

```
$words = explode('-',$string);
$result = array();

foreach($words as $word) 
{
if( ($word ==preg_replace("([^a-z])", "-", $word)) && strlen($word)>2)  
$result[]=$word;
}
$string = implode(' ',$result);
```

This does not work now as it contains foreign characters.

Comment: Related: [Regex to delete words with numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10315560/55075).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, you have access to Unicode properties:

```
$result = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}-]+/u', '', $subject);
```

will do step 1 for you. (`\p{L}` matches any Unicode letter, `\p{N}` matches any Unicode digit).

Removing words with digits is just as easy:

```
$result2 = preg_replace('/\b\w*\d\w*\b-?/', '', $result);
```

(`\b` matches the start and end of a word).

Comment: The last example works for general strings like `a2c4`, but it also removes digits from the prices, such as `$100` making it `$`, or `$25.25` making it `$.`, which is a bit not expected if you want to just remove words with digits.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly suggest to transliterate the unicode characters if you are actually doing slugs for links. You can use [PHP's iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to achieve that.

---

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315560/regex-to-delete-words-with-numbers). The ingenuity and simplicity of the top voted answer, I think, is great:)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing this in multiple steps:

1. Create a string of allowed characters ( all of them ) and and go through the string by keeping only them. ( it will take some time, but it's a one time thing )
2. Do an explode on `-` and go through all the words and keep only the ones, that don't contain numbers. Then implode it again.

I believe, you can write the script on your own from now.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, creating a list of allowed characters may be difficult as there will be too many.